# Passing information to template from multiple databases with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have to pass multiple databases info with Laravel. I always do this:

```
public function get_view(){
        $myinfo = MyDatabases::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
        return view('auth.view')->with('myinfo',$myinfo);
    }
```

I need to pass info from other databases. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some db in your file app/config/database.php ?

```
'connections' => [

        'mysql1' => [

        ],

        'mysql2' => []
]
```

You can use :

```
\DB::connection('mysql1')->table()->where(....)

\DB::connection('mysql2')->table()->where(....)
```

and you can create some help function or Facade, where you can aggregate this queries